# How can I drop off construction supplies to build storage?

Tags: x4-foundations

How can I dock with build storage to transfer construction supplies?

Build storage doesn't show up on the map, so can't be targetted from there. Targetting buttons won't target it when it's directly in front of you. Cycling through all local targets doesn't target it. Flying near it and opening the action menu doesn't have a request docking permission item. Flying into the docking ports doesn't trigger a docking permission request.

Interacting with the station doesn't work either:

[image: Can't request permission to dock to transfer wares to Build Storage]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Build Storage seems to only be targettable automatically if you have no current target and are near it. Click on empty space when you're near the build storage to clear your target.